# Emacs - help() output in web-browser

Tags: emacs, browser, r, ess

I started using Emacs (ESS) as a default R editor (yes, @Dirk, as you've said, I want ESS), and I must admit it's by far  **the best** `R` editor I've been using so far. However, I cannot manage to get an output of `help()` function up to web browser. It keeps displaying help page in a separate R buffer, even if `options(help_type = "html", browser = "firefox")` are set.

How can I get help back to browser, while using Emacs/ESS?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: You may want to 'offer' one of the tags so that we can create a tag 'ess' :-)

Comment: @JD Long, I'm using Ubuntu 9.10, Emacs v23.1.1, ESS v5.8. @Dirk, thanks for stressing the "ESS-tag" idea, "output" tag was absolutely trivial! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can reproduce this under Linux: If I run R from the terminal, setting `options(htmlhelp=TRUE)` brings up help in a browser, but it fails from ESS.  However,

```
help("plot",htmlhelp=getOption("htmlhelp"))
```

works -- help opens in Firefox for me.  I think that's an anomalous behavior -- htmlhelp=getOption("htmlhelp") is a default argument for help (see ?help).  Could it be a bug?..  A possible workaround is to invoke help via `help("plot",htmlhelp=T)` directly, or write a wrapper like `myhelp <- function(x) help(x,htmlhelp=TRUE)`.

EDIT: A possible solution: put this into your .emacs

```
(setq inferior-ess-r-help-command "help(\"%s\", htmlhelp=TRUE)\n")
```

as per https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/ess-debian/2009-October/000093.html.  This refers to ESS 5.5; the current one in Ubuntu repositories is 5.4, so I can't test the fix w/o upgrading ESS.

EDIT2: I upgraded to the latest R/ESS as per Dirk's suggestion, and did the following, after launching R/ESS: `M-x customize-variable`  `inferior-ess-r-help-command` and replaced help_type=text with help_type=html.  That fixed things (at least for version 2.10.1/ESS 5.8).

Comment: ESS 5.8 is available for Ubuntu _if_ you use the apt-get'able repo at CRAN -- see $CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu

Comment: @Leo, thanks for workaround, it works for me. Could you, please be more precise with the location of an `.emacs` file? I've tried `locate .emacs` but with no luck... BTW, I thought that `option(htmlhelp = TRUE)` was deprecated in R v2.10.x, if not since v2.9.x ?!

Comment: Yup, the link that I posted was discussing 2.9, I believe.  I just figured out a clean way to do this w/o editing .emacs -- see my updated edit2.  But to figure out where your .emacs is, do C-h v user-init-file, this gives the value of the variable where path to the file is stored.  Typically it is either ~/.emacs or ~/.emacs.d/init.el (but people still refer to it as .emacs)

Comment: Great! And now ~/.emacs file was created. But there's a downside: help page is opened in Opera, although Firefox is default.

Comment: Run C-h v browse-url-browser-function, is that set to Opera or FF?  If opera, try customizing it so that its value is browse-url-firefox.

Comment: Sorry, it had to do something with E17 environment settings... after changing it in E17, it works fine with Firefox. Thanx a lot mate!